# js_of_ocaml and Deriving_Json

Tags: javascript, json, ocaml, deriving, js-of-ocaml

I need some help to get js_of_ocaml working. There's not much information about it on the net, and the manual is very sparse (no snippets or usage examples, no comment sections).

I have a `Card` module on the server with a `card` record. I'm  sending a `card list` to the client using Ajax, and there I want to read and traverse this list. What I end up with is this:

```
let json = Json.unsafe_input (Js.string http_frame.XmlHttpRequest.content) in
```

...where `json` has type `'a`, according to documentation (not when I run it, of course).

I can log `json##length` and get the correct length of the list. Where do I go from here? Ideally, I'd like to use `Deriving_Json` to type-safe get a `card list` again, but I could also use a for-loop (not as elegant, but whatever).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type declarations like `type name = ... deriving(Json)` creates `Json_name` module.
Here is example.

```
type card =  {a: int; b: string; } deriving(Json)
type t = card list deriving(Json)

let _ =
  let str = Json.to_string<t> [{a = 10; b = "abc";}; {a = 20; b = "xyz";}] in
  let rs = Json.from_string<t> str in
  Firebug.console##log(Js.string str);
  List.iter (fun r -> Firebug.console##log_2(r.a, Js.string r.b)) rs
```

And I'm not sure why, I got "Uncaught ReferenceError: unix_inet_addr_of_string is not defined".

So add `function unix_inet_addr_of_string () {return 0;}` to js file.